# How to test RxJS observable that emits multiple values in 1 frame?

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, rxjs-test-scheduler

Given the following code:

```
import {merge, Observable} from "rxjs";

export function springLatch(handle$: Observable<boolean>, closedByDefault: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    const latch$ = new Observable<boolean>((subscriber) => {
        if (closedByDefault) {
            subscriber.next(false);
        } else {
            subscriber.next(true);
        }
        handle$.subscribe({
            next(value: boolean) {
                if (closedByDefault && value) {
                    subscriber.next(value);

                } else {
                    subscriber.next(value);
                }
            }
        })
    });

    return merge(handle$, latch$);
}
```

Tested by this unit-test:

```
describe('SpringLatchTest', () => {
    let testScheduler: TestScheduler;
    beforeEach(() => {
        testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
            expect(actual).toBe(expected);
        });
    });

    it('should do something', () => {
        testScheduler.run(({cold, expectObservable}) => {
            // Assemble
            const handle$ = cold('-t-f', {t: true, f: false});
            // Act
            const actual: Observable<boolean> = springLatch(handle$, true);
            // Assert
            expectObservable(actual).toBe('fttff', {t: true, f: false});
        });
    });
});
```

Based on the above I have several questions related to value emissions and frames.

- How do I prevent the unit-test from failing due to mismatching frames between the actual observable and the expected observable based on the marble diagram?
- Do values emissions have a a 1-to-1 relationship with frames?

Versioning

```
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"rxjs": "^7.8.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS has a very good documentation regarding [RxJS marble testing](https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing). If you need to test that there were multiple `next` emissions within the same frame you can wrap expected emissions with parenthesis `()`.

For example, `'(fttff)'` means all emissions happened at frame `0`. Or `'(ft)(tff)'` means `ft` were emitted at frame `0` and then `tff` at frame `4`.

There's a known limitation with marble tests. You can't expect groups of emissions that would overlap because each group start at char index of its `(`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, I can't believe I read passed that.

Comment: Question. I just tested this and it seems that I am not getting the results I was expecting.
Reading the documentation: '--(abc)-|': on frame 2 emit a, b, and c, then on frame 8, complete. Whereas what I would expect is: on frame 2 emit a, b, and c, then on frame 5, complete. I tested this out with TestScheduler.parseMarbles('(tf)(tf)', {t: true, f: false}); and I'm getting the first 2 emissions on frame 0 and the second on frame 4. Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: I just saw you already had this in your answer. My bad. Still it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: I agree it isn't completely obvious and sometimes confusing. But when you get used to it and you're aware of possible issues, it's great :).